# Paperclip undefined method 'after_commit'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm working on a project that uses paperclip (4.3.7) with ruby (2.2.7) and rails (3.2.22) to upload images to S3. Locally, everything works like a charm, but when I pushed the project to Heroku I've received this error:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/paperclip-4.3.7/lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb:94:in `add_active_record_callbacks': undefined method `after_commit' for JobApplication:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Someone has any idea of what may be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i have solved the problem by using an older version of Paperclip (`2.7.0`) and moving the paperclip configurations to the models itself, instead of the `production.rb` file. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

can you update to a newer version of Rails? [Paperclip's github repo](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) says that they require rails >= 4.2. I think you may be hitting a bug in paperclip.

If you're not able to upgrade Rails, then consider adding an after_commit method to the JobApplication class. You may have to look at the paperclip source code to find out what hook they are trying to add and decide if you can live without that functionality or it needs to be recreated. It may or may not be vitally important.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. I could downgrade paperclip version, though.

Comment: The reason I haven't is because I was having issues with the 2.7.0 version not returning the right urls.

Answer (score 0):

before pushing to Heroku have u done asset_precomplie?

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

> rake assets: precompile (RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake
>   assets: precompile is the exact rake task)

Since pre compilation is done in production mode only, no need to explicitly specify the environment.

Hope it will work :)